# MAAS - PXE boot only working with Legacy boot not UEFI

Tags: maas

I've noticed that I can't get MAAS to enlist or commission boxes that are set to UEFI PXE boot. Only legacy works. How can I get UEFI PXE booting working. One of my best boxes has no legacy boot option int he BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with my setup. Here is a thread with details from others trying the same and my solution. https://discourse.maas.io/t/pxe-boot-forward-with-uefi-support/590